# Only part of JQuery executable. When pasted in HTML directly everything works (window.location)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, external

I have a JS file, which works flawlessly, and executes all the code in it.

But I now added the following JQuery:

```
$("#need2Know").click(function(){
        window.location ="URLString";           
        return false;
});


$("#nice2Know").click(function(){
        window.location ="URLString";           
        return false;
});
```

When I call this part of the code in the HTML file, the onclick Handling executes as expected.
However, as soon as I paste it in the JS file (above all other code, the remainder of the code still working), the onclick handling does not work anymore.

I use the following JQuery library:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

My JQ file is called after this library.

What is so strange to me is, that the code works in HTML but not in the JS file, although the rest of the code still processes as before...

Any advice on how to fix this, so the click-handling can be performed in the JS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently what you are using is called a "direct" binding which will only attach to element that exist on the page at the time your code makes the event binding call. As the DOM is not loaded yet, no event handlers are attached.

You can solve the problem by one of these methods:

1. Wrap the code in [**document-ready**](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) handler.

> > Specify a function to execute when the DOM is fully loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

});
```

2. Move the reference to the file to bottom of the `<body>` element.

Comment: Thank you, worked like a charm. For some reasons, I thought the $document.ready Query would make my code too messy in the long run, but I do definitely see its advantages^^

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```
$("body").on("click","#nice2Know", function(){
    window.location ="URLString";
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Why should they try this? what problem is it solving?